# How to use PropTypes with Typescript in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

I am trying to use PropTypes with Typescript but getting errors:

Without typescript I was able to use:

```
class TodoFilterItem extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
```

and then at the bottom

```
TodoFilterItem.propTypes = {
  name: PropTypes.string,
  filter: PropTypes.string,
  filterTodos: PropTypes.any
}
```

and that worked for just having PropTypes (i.e. no typescript).

However when I add Typescript and I have

```
class TodoFilterItem extends Component<ITodoFilterItem> {
  constructor (props:ITodoFilterItem) {
    super(props);
    ...
```

I have props as an interface like this:

```
interface ITodoFilterItem  {
  filter: string,
  name: string,
  filterTodos: any
}
```

and I use the same propTypes:

```
TodoFilterItem.propTypes = {
  filter: PropTypes.string,
  name: PropTypes.string,
  filterTodos: PropTypes.any
}
```

I get an error

```
Property 'propTypes' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/my_adrs/node_modules/@types/prop-types/index")'.
```

How to address this and be able to use PropTypes with Typescript in React ?

Comment: Related discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54712094/1915893

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PropTypes are separate from Typescript. To reuse your `propTypes` you have to convert it to an interface or type.

This

```js
TodoFilterItem.propTypes = {
  filter: PropTypes.string,
  name: PropTypes.string,
  filterTodos: PropTypes.any
}
```

becomes

```js
interface ITodoFilterItem {
  filter: string;
  name: string;
  filterTodos: any; 
}
```

Using that interface is simple, you replace `TodoFilterItemProps` with `ITodoFilterItem`.

The convention is to name your component props `IProps`. Putting that together your component now looks like:

```js
interface IProps { 
 name: string;
 filter: string;
 filterTodos: any; 
}

class TodoFilterItem extends Component<IProps> {
  constructor (props:IProps) {
    super(props);
    ...
```

**Note on `any`**

Try to avoid typing to `any`. `any` type is the same has untyped. I imagine `filterTodos` is an array of `todos`. If that's the case you can create a type for `todo` call it

```
type Todo = { ...properties of a todo }
```

then type `filterTodos` to be an array of `Todo` which would look like this:

```js
type Todo = { 
  name: string,
  status: 'not started' | 'in progress' | 'done'
}

interface IProps { 
  filter: string;
  name: string;
  filterTodos: Todo[]; 
}
```

Comment: This helps but unfortunately I am getting an error that `Property 'propTypes' does not exist on type `typeof TodoFilterItems`

Comment: in the `TodoFiterItem.propTypes` at the bottom of the file.

Comment: You can remove your prop types all together. Typescript is a replacement for your prop types essentially

Comment: @BensSteves Sadly it isn't quite. It doesn't provide details for props that are passed as a null value for a required prop at runtime, for example.